# Remove sections from VS2017 Pending Changes panel

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

We are still getting adjusted to VS2017, after upgrading from VS2010, and noticed that the Pending Changes panel was redesigned sometime between these releases.  Our team of 2 will never use the Related Work Items and Notes (Code Reviewer, Security Reviewer, etc.) sections so is it possible to remove them somehow?

[image]

I realize each sections can be closed but this is not restored with future VS sessions and, even so, they still take up valuable real estate.  FWIW, replacing the simple checkboxes with the "Included Changes" and "Excluded Changes" sections seems to require many more clicks than before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Notes** is not a new feature in VS2017.  **Administrators** of Team Foundation version control can add, configure, and remove [check-in notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/configure-check-notes).

> **To remove check-in notes**
>
> 1. On the **Team** menu, click **Team Project Settings**, and then
>      click **Source Control**.
> 2. In the **Source Control Settings** dialog box, click the **Check-in
>      Notes** tab.
> 3. Select the check-in note title that you want to remove, and click
>      **Remove**.

[image]

As for the **Related Work Items**, it's not possible to disable or fold the section for now. If you need this feature, you could add a [uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services), TFS PM will kindly review your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks! +1 for screen shot and UserVoice link.

Comment: I removed the fields as you described and they disappeared from the Pending Changes panel.  When I opened the solution the next day, Check-in Notes under Source Control Settings was still blank but, those fields reappeared again.

Comment: @ESS Could not reproduce it in my side.  Maybe it's a cache issue,  [clear TFS and VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) and  try again.

Comment: This is strange. I removed those fields again and they haven't reappeared yet. The only thing that happened that may have triggered the reappearance before is that my colleague open the solution. These settings aren't shared via the solution are they?

Comment: @ESS It is team project level. All solutions under the team project should be  influenced. Haven't encountered such a situation like you ever. Guess maybe a cache issue. After all it's a source control system,  could not 100% assurance that others did not affect the operation what you were doing.

Answer (score 3):

You can't remove the related work items section. The three "Notes" fields are things that someone configured at some point. [You can turn those off in the Team Project Settings section of the team explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181460.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! +1 for first answer and link.